# implement tflite on tensorflow library

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

i have done tensorflow object detection to counting object. but i want to cange it to tensorflow Lite model. for example i have TF model loader bellow, how to change this code to support tflite models? i'm new on tflite, i'm so confused.

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

any helps will be appriciate
thankyou

Comment: Have you looked at the [TensorFlow Lite Python quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python)?

Comment: What tensorflow version are u using?